# Django style multiple apps with web.py not working

Tags: web.py

I run the example in the tutorial [Django style multiple apps with web.py](http://webpy.org/multiple_apps), but it does not working. The following is error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 11, in <module>
    delegate.run(mapping)
  File "/home/siongui/dev/test/delegate.py", line 31, in run
    web.run(handler, {})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

My web.py version is 0.37. Is there any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.
(subapp is not a option for me.)

Answer (score 0):

There is some addition for the application module in 0.3 (http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/)

> Applications. How to map urls to python code paths.
>   - Basic app. Map regexes to classes.
>   - Auto app. Have webpy keep track of the urls based on class name.
>   - Subdir app. Host multiple apps based on the sub-directory.
>   - Subdomain app. Host multiple apps based on the subdomain.

Following this cookbook should get things to work.
http://webpy.org/cookbook/subapp

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier than the example provided at webpy.org.

Updating that [Django style multiple apps](http://webpy.org/multiple_apps) example:

1. Keep `wiki.py`, and `blog.py` as specified in the example
2. don't bother with `delegate.py` hack: it's no longer needed.
3. change `run.py` to:

   ```
   """run.py"""
   import web
   import wiki
   import blog

   urls = ("/blog", blog.app_blog,
           "/wiki", wiki.app_wiki,
           "/(.*)", "index")

   class index:
       def GET(self, path):
           return "other: " + path

   app = web.application(urls, locals())

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run()
   ```

The key change is the urls specified in `run.py`. If the second item is a string (`"index"` in the above example) then web.py expects that to be a class to handle the matching url (`"/(.*)"` in the example). This is the way webpy normally works.

However, if the second item is type `application` (`blog.app_blog`, for example), then the matching url (`/blog`) isn't a regex, it's a prefix & all incoming requests matching that prefix are handed to the related `application` (and the prefix is removed from the incoming request).