# Need to run separate python apps using web.py, examples on site don't work

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, web.py

Trying to build small python apps to have them hosted and accessible from a main web page, stored on server in their own subdirectories. I am on python2.7 with web.py 0.37

On http://webpy.org/multiple_apps the key piece of code is simple:

```
"""run.py"""    import blog
import wiki
import delegate

mapping = (
    ("/blog", blog.urls, blog),
    ("/wiki", wiki.urls, wiki)
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    delegate.run(mapping)
```

AND the first offending bit of code is in the the last line of delegate.py:

```
web.run(handler, {})
```

The code for delegate.py is part of the example linked in the first paragraph. The 'run()' function is in web.application(), not web, so that's the first error. I just don't know how to get around it. Perhaps I am trying to use web.py the wrong way?

I have looked through documentation, some other examples and the google code forum with no luck. Also I've tried replacing the mapping tuple with the urls = (url, class) set up, no success.

I'm new to python and web.py, what am I missing?

Comment: I looked at the API and it seems to conflict with this example - the only thing I can think is to try and change it to web.application.run, but I'm guessing you already tried that

Comment: Yes, thanks. Delegate_apps is a nested function, so when I tried web.application.run(handler, {}) I get a 'function object not iterable' or a 'function object not callable'.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple apps example code at webpy.org is obsolete. Fortunately, it's even easier to implement now.

See the answer [Django style multiple apps with web.py not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007882/django-style-multiple-apps-with-web-py-not-working/40683613#40683613)